# Meaning of "two most mornings"

Tags: meaning

In "Outliers"

Here is Pete Best, the Beatles' drummer at the time : "Once the news got out
about that we were making a show, the club started packing them in. We
played seven nights a week, At first played almost nonstop **till twelve-thirty**,
when it closed, but as we got better the crowds stayed till **two most mornings**."

1. till twelve-thirty -> till 12 O'clock 30 minutes(that is, means time), Is this correct?
2. two most mornings, what does it mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, 12:30 is a time.

So is 2:00.

(On) most mornings, we played until 2 a.m.

Note that some people, myself included, would call that a night!

Comment: thank you for answer